# Error On button click event in Android Phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a button in my phonegap HTML page to which i have added a button click event and ajax call to webservice URL.At present i am not calling any webservice URL but the main issue that i have is that my button click event is not getting fired .on logcat it is giving following error..

```
stale touch event action_down received from webcore ignoring
```

Here is my button HTML code..

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; background-color: green;">
<button id="call" class="button">Call</button>
</div>
```

and here is my js file code for button click event ..

```
//Add event listener to run when the device is ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//Device is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#call').bind('click',function(evt){
    senddata();
});
});
} 

function senddata(){  
e.preventDefault();             
var empname=$("#name").text();
alert(empname); 

var contactno=$("#contact").text();
alert(contactno); 

//Webservice URL
var URL="index.html";

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    data: "",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: '+e);
    }  
});
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bind()` just use the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Login_button', function() {

//Call your method to call webservice.

senddata();

}
```

or other way to add click event to button is following:

```
<button id="call" onclick="senddata();">Call</button>
```

Comment: `#Login_button` this i need to replace with my button id ..right sir ? and do i need to add this code inside function `function onDeviceReady() {`?

Comment: @sanatanmishra:Yes.Right

Comment: I added `function onDeviceReady() {
              $(document).on('click', '#Call', function() {
              //Call your method to call webservice.
                 senddata();
              });
            } ` code but still i am not able to see any alert message ..Why

Comment: Write the above code outside the onDeviceReady() method.

Comment: I added it outside as you advised but now getting `stale touch event action_down received from webcore ignoring`  and `up` error but not alert messages ..Even i can see the button is clicked visually but not alert message ..Why sir ?

Comment: Sir i have one more query here ..actually the HTML page transition from one page to another is very slow in phonegap ..I am talking about `<li><a href="empdetails.html"`..Why and is there any way to speed it up.